# Help with $\int\frac{(x-2)}{x\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

i'm trying to solve this integral, but i feel lost.

So far,

$$\int\frac{(x-2)}{x\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}}dx=\int\frac{(x-1)-1}{x\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x^{2}-(x-1)}}dx$$

Now, let $u = x-1$ then $du = dx$

$$\int\frac{(x-1)-1}{x\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x^{2}-(x-1)}}dx = \int\frac{u-1}{(u+1)\sqrt{u}\sqrt{(u+1)^{2}-u}}du$$

It is fine? What can i do next? I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Wolfram gives a very bad primitive, are you sure that the is integral correct? [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x-2%29%2F%28x*sqrt%28x-1%29*sqrt%28x%5E2-x-1%29%29)

Comment: @Sewer, in general, Alpha (and *Mathematica* by extension) is not very good at recognizing when an elliptic integral degenerates to an elementary function.

Answer (score 2):

I did it (I think so). This is what i got.

$\int\frac{x-2}{x\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x^{2}-x+1}}dx$

= $\int$$\frac{x^{2}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^{2}})}{x\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x^{2}(1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x2})}}dx$

= $\int\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{2}})}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}}dx$

Let $u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$  get $du=\frac{\frac{2}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}}dx$

then $dx=\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}}{\frac{2}{x^{3}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}du$

Replacing we get:

$-2\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}$ (I omitted some details, but replacement
is easy)

= $-2arcsen(u)=-2arcsen($ $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}})$+
C